# Trying to fetch a Postman API and displaying the contents of the array using map function. It says the array is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, api

The API fetches a json object which contains an array of objects. This array is taken out and passed to the component below as a prop (props.users).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import UserCard from '../components/UserCard';

export class Userscreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {users: []};
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const people =  this.props.users;
        this.setState({users: people});
    }

    render() {

        let UserList = this.state.users.map(user => 
            <UserCard name={user.firstName+' '+user.lastName} id={user.id} email={user.email} dob={user.dob} />
        );
        return (
            <div>
                {UserList}                
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Userscreen
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't copy props to state. Just use the props directly:

```
export class Userscreen extends Component {
    render() {
        let UserList = this.props.users.map(user => 
        // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
            <UserCard name={user.firstName+' '+user.lastName} id={user.id} email={user.email} dob={user.dob} />
        );
        return (
            <div>
                {UserList}                
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Props are basically parent-controlled state. By copying them to state, you're capturing the **first** `props.users` your component was called with, and then ignoring any updates the parent makes after that. That's why the list was empty: Presumably, your parent component starts out creating `Userscreen` with an empty list of users while the ajax call is running, and then updates it when the ajax call is complete.

---

Side note: Since this component is now pure, you might consider converting it to a stateless functional component:

```
export function Userscreen(props) {
    let UserList = props.users.map(user => 
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^
        <UserCard name={user.firstName+' '+user.lastName} id={user.id} email={user.email} dob={user.dob} />
    );
    return (
        <div>
            {UserList}                
        </div>
    );
}
```

Or with destructuring:

```
export function Userscreen({users}) {
    let UserList = users.map(({firstName, lastName, id, email, dob}) => 
        <UserCard name={firstName + ' ' + lastName} id={id} email={email} dob={dob} />
    );
    return (
        <div>
            {UserList}                
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution, still the same error. If I try to log the users.props before mapping on it by console.log(props.users); it prints the object just fine. Only has problem mapping it.

Comment: @Dungeonmaster - This answer corrects the issue with the code shown in the question, and definitely works if the parent re-renders when it has the list of users. If it's not working, that suggests either A) You haven't implemented it as above (Sorry :-) ), or B) There's a separate problem with the parent component. Please double-check that you've correctly implemented the above, and if it's a parent component problem, post a new question about the parent component. In that question please include a **runnable** example; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).